# Java Thumbnail View

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, thumbnails

Hey i want to create a thumbnail viewer, for my app, i want something similar to this.
[image]

I was wondering if there is a pre-existing component that can display thumbnails (FREE), or i was considering to use a JTable, with a custom cell renderer.

What do you think, what would be the best way.

It will be used to display images, keep in mind that i must be able to select individual and multiple files to perform actions on them.

thx in advance.

Comment: Java 2D is what I would go for. Google: java graphics2d tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JList would probably be better than a JTable. You can use a "horizontal wrap" style. You can always create a custom renderer for the list as well.

Comment: Thx I will give your suggestion a try